# Cumulative integration of sin(x)/x

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

I'm trying to plot the integral of sin(x)/x by means of obtaining a cumulative sum of the area beneath sin(x)/x.

```
def y(x):
a = np.sin(x) / x
a[np.isnan(a)] = 1 # (Lim y(x)--> 0) = 1
return a
```

I tried using a for loop for a left Riemann sum:

```
a = -56.5
b = 56.5
n = 1000
x = np.linspace(a,b,n)
I = np.zeros(n)

for i in range(n):
    I[i] = (y(x[:i+2])).sum()*(b-a)/n
```

Using `np.cumsum()`:

```
I = np.cumsum(y(x))*(b-a)/n
```

And using `scipy.integrate` with trapezoid method:

```
from scipy import integrate
I = integrate.cumulative_trapezoid(y(x), x, initial=0)
```

All the methods mentioned give the following:

[image]

But according to Wolfram Alpha the expected behavior should look like:
[image]

As you can see, the integral takes values  between [-2, 2] (roughly speaking), but by doing cumulative sums it takes values out of that range, and it worsens as one make use of bigger intervals. Any ideas on why this is the case? I'm very likely having a severe case of tunnel-vision here, so I would appreciate any comments.

Comment: The wolfram page says it is plotting Si(x), which perhaps is the integral between 0 and x (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sinc_function).  Whereas your cumsum calculates the integral from -56.5 to x.  Does that explain the difference?

Comment: Now I see. If one integrates `sin(x)/(x)` in `{a,b}` they just integrate in two parts as @oda suggested, from `{a,0}` which they actually do as inverting the limits and it is just the negative of Si(x), and the rest `{0,b}` is again Si(x). Told you I was tunneling.

Btw the changing nan to 1 is just because of the warning of division by zero, not an actual error, and is correct to change it as the limit of sin(x)/x when x tends to 0 is 1.

Comment: If any of you want to coment as an actual answer I will be glad to mark it for any of you. Thanks.

Comment: @DavidBarcene Actually what has happened is you have misinterpreted the Wolfram Alpha graph. It is not meant to be aligned with the cumulative sum graph that you have made.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wolfram is calculating/graphing, `Si(x)`, defined as the integral of `sin(x) / x` between `0` and `x`.

If you change `a` to `0` and `b` to any positive number or `b` to 0 and `a` to any negative number, you will see that the integral lies within that rough `-2` to `2` band you mentioned.

That Wolfram graph is not meant to coincide with your cumulative sum graph. The `-2` to `2` band does not represent the range of possible values one can get from integrating `sin(x) / x` over some interval.

FYI, the limit of `Si(x)` as `x` gets arbitrarily large is `pi / 2`. Similarly, the limit of `Si(x)` as `x` approaches negative infinity is `-pi / 2`.

Comment: The interval I mentioned was just rougly by the visuals of the graph, but thanks.